Solve advection numerically
I try to solve the velocity advection equation numerically.
Advecting a scalar quantity like temperature works very well when using a fully implicit upwind-scheme based euler approach.
I have tried to achieve a similar result with regards to advection of velocity itself.
The issue is that the equation isn't linear anymore since the advection equation (in 1d for simplicity) looks like this in discretized form:
$$\ \frac{u_{i}^{\left(n+1\right)}-u_{i}^{\left(n\right)}}{dt}=\ -u_{i}^{\left(n+1\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{u_{i}^{\left(n+1\right)}-u_{i+1}^{\left(n+1\right)}}{dx}\right)$$
As you can see, when multiplying out I am ending up with a non-linear function since it's
$$\ \left(u_{i}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)^{2}$$
(Notice that (n+1) is a superscript denoting the time step, i.e. next time step).
Suppose the velocity u is every negative.. my idea then was to linearize the problem by introducing newton-raphson-method.
My residual function becomes
$$\ F\left(u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)=\frac{u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}-u_{i}^{\left(n\right)}}{dt}+u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}-u_{i+1}^{\left(n+1\right)}}{dx}\right)$$
measuring how far I am from the solution.
Which then yields:
$$\ u_{i,\ new}^{\left(n+1\right)}=u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\ -\ J\left(F\left(u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)\right)^{-1}\cdot F\left(u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)$$
wheras J denotes the jacobian.
I then bring $\ u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}$ to the RHS and multiply by J which yields
$$\ J\left(F\left(u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)\right)\Delta u=-F\left(u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}\right)$$
I use jacobi method to find delta u and then update the formula like so:
$$\ u_{i,\ new}^{\left(n+1\right)}=u_{i,\ old}^{\left(n+1\right)}+\Delta u$$
This is my code:
private void ImplicitStep()
{
    for (int newton_iterations = 0; newton_iterations < 20; newton_iterations++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
            {
                residuals_u[i + j * N] =
                    (u_next[i + j * N] - u_current[i + j * N]) / dt + u_next[i + j * N] * (u_next[i + j * N] - u_next[i + 1 + j * N]) / dx;
            }
        }

        for (int jacobian_iterations = 0; jacobian_iterations < 100; jacobian_iterations++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = N - 2; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    float df_di = 1.0f / dt + (2.0f * u_next[i + j * N] - u_next[i + 1 + j * N]) / dx;
                    float df_di_1 = -u_next[i + j * N] / dx;
                    delta_u[i + j * N] = (-residuals_u[i + j * N] - df_di_1 * delta_u[i + 1 + j * N]) / df_di;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
            {
                u_next[i + j * N] += delta_u[i + j * N];
            }
        }
    }
}

It doesn't work as expected. It even leads to bunch of NaN since df_di becomes zero.
What am I missing?
My dt is 1/60, meaning after 60 steps, one second has passed.
Secondly, could I use semi-lagrangian approach for velocity advection and implicit upwind approach for scalar quantities?

It might help to pinpoint the exact problem by inserting some checks: does the resulting $\Delta u$ vector solve the linear system after Jacobi iterations? Does the value of $F(u_i^{(n)})$ tend to zero before blowing up?

Seems to be the Inviscid Burgers' equation:
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2} u(x,t)^2\right)=\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+u(x,t)\cdot \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$$
With the initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ there exists an implicit solution:
$$u(x,t)=f(x-t\cdot u(x,t))$$
OP's discretization seems to be unstable!
I would like to propose another discretization scheme with central finite differences of $2^{nd}$ order:
$$\frac{-u_i^{(n-1)}+u_i^{(n+1)}}{2\,\mathrm{dt}}+u_i^{(n+1)}\cdot \frac{-u_{i-1}^{(n+1)}+u_{i+1}^{(n+1)}}{2\,\mathrm{dx}}=0$$
These equations may be solved with a nonlinear solver (e.g. MATLAB's fsolve).
Demonstration example
IC: $u(x,0)=f(x):=\sin^2(\pi x)\cdot(\theta(x)-\theta(x-1))$
BCs: $u(0,t)=0 \land u(L,t)=0$
$L=1.2, T_{max}=0.3$
Hint: $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside theta function.
See also MATLAB implementation MSE_Q4986537


